# Misunderstanding of amplifiying a current with transistor

Tags: transistors, current, proteus, darlington, common-collector

Electrical books say that we can use transistor to amplifying current but when I simulate a circuit in proteus input current, it is smaller than emitter current but why?

This is a common collector and we expect that the current to be amplified at the emitter point.

[image: I at p1 point is greater than I at p2]

Comment: @horta and em fields and peter bennett
ok! so what is the benefit of transistor? i connect directly motor to power supply and dont need transistor.

Comment: You can't amplify the current of the battery/power supply with the transistor, the transistor is used so that MCUs and other devices can deal with higher currents than they would be able to.

Comment: Transistor is not a source of any current or voltage (transistor is not a battery). What is happening is that the base current is controlling the amount of current that transistor can pass from supplies voltage to the load. Just like a water tap.

Comment: @G36 can you say a simple example or compare with another  devices? thanks alot

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplifier

Comment: Also transistor gives you ability to control the OFF/ON state just like a switch. https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/transistors/applications-i-switches

Comment: here i want use transistor as a dc current amplifier.

Comment: But transistor can only control the amount of current that can flow through it into the load. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Transistor_animation.gif  In your circuit you can use a pot (RV1) to change the speed of a motor. Notice that the base current is small.

Comment: @G36 
so i cant increase current by transistor and only i can control out put current by use of base current. in other words transistor can pressure to power supply to get its maximum output.
Thank you for sharing your wisdom with me.

Comment: The transistor is able to control a high current flowing through the transistor from collector to emitter by a small current current flowing from base to emitter (or by a help of a Vbe voltage), so its said to have a current gain. But this "large" current must be provide by the external supply source.  
The transistor does not create the current, it simply controls the current flowing around the loop. http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/1684819100_1479844125.png

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be comparing the current supplied by the battery to the current from the transistor's emitter.  This is incorrect.

Some of the current from the battery will flow through the potentiometer, so the emitter current must be less than the battery current.

The gain of a transistor in this circuit is the ratio of the emitter current to the base current.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting current amplification. Ib to Ie is getting amplified: 0.15mA -> 6.5mA. That's a current gain of ~43X.

The output of the battery has to account for all of this current so that's why it's greater than Ie. A little bit of current from the battery flows through the 10K resistor which is why the battery current shows more current than any other point.

To be clear, a transistor amplifies current between its nodes. It **cannot** make a battery source more current than the battery will output on its own. The exception to this is if you have a boost converter or a circuit that isn't just aimed at regulating current.